# How to layout widgets in a Python Tkinter frame under a root TopLevel

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code:

```
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('GUI')

        row = 0
        self.s_date_label = Label(self, text = 'Start Date: ')
        self.s_date_label.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky = W)
        self.start_date = Entry(self, bd=1)
        self.start_date.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky = W)
        self.s_date_label2 = Label(self, text = 'example: 20160101')
        self.s_date_label2.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky = W)

        self.datetype_var = IntVar()
        R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="20160101", variable=self.datetype_var, value=8)
        R1.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky = W)
        R1.select()
        R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="201601", variable=self.datetype_var, value=6)
        R2.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky = W)
        R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="2016", variable=self.datetype_var, value=4)
        R3.grid(row=row, column=3, sticky = W)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Here is the output:

[image]

My Label and Entry both do not show up.

I have found that Radiobutton do not have self. and Label and Entry have it.

However, I don't know why this will cause the result.

Comment: What do you mean, you "found" that they're attached to different objects? Did you not write this yourself?

Comment: I write them all by myself. But originally I use place() to build the layout, but finally I try to use grid() to build the layout. And obviously it did not work well...

Comment: And why didn't you try attaching them to the same object?

Comment: I think if I add self., it will become global parameter in class Window. But the Radiobutton is not necessary to become global in Class Window. I only need Entry start_date. So I only add self. to Entry start_date.

Comment: Adding `self` makes it the _opposite_ of global. And I mean why didn't you try `self.s_date_label = Label(root...` instead of `self.s_date_label = Label(self...`, if you noticed that as a key difference between the ones that did work and the ones that didn't?

Comment: @MarsLee I suggest improving the question by choosing a title more relevant to the problem, rather than this specific instance of the problem. like: "How to layout widgets in a Python Tkinter frame under a root TopLevel". So it might help others as well. Thanks.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I got it! In fact, we have a misunderstanding. However, I now know what exactly you are talking about! I think your method is better. I should use both root rather than one root and one self.

Comment: @farzad I have changed the title. Since I am not native speaker of English. Hope you don't mind my unclear discription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

I had suggested 2 approaches to solve this. First one is to use the `root` Tk object as the parent for all the widgets; Second is to add the widgets to `Window`, and add `Window` object to the layout manager of the `root`.
 As Bryan Oakley mentioned (correctly) in the comments, the first approach is not as good (although it works, but still). So I'm suggesting to use the second approach (discussed below), which is:

Make sure all the widgets (`Radiobutton`, `Label`, `Entry`, etc.) are using the `Window` object (referenced by `self`) as the parent, and then add the window instance to the layout manager of the `root`. Either in `init_window` call, or after creating the object.

**Approach 1**

The widgets under the `Window`, should use `self` as the parent (to preserve hierarchy), and the `Window` itself, should be added to layout manager of `master`. This way all the widgets will show correctly

You should have passed the Tk object (referenced by `root`) when adding the widgets to the layout (in this case the `grid` geometry).

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title('GUI')

        row = 0
        self.s_date_label = Label(self.master, text = 'Start Date: ')
        self.s_date_label.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky = W)
        self.start_date = Entry(self.master, bd=1)
        self.start_date.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky = W)
        self.s_date_label2 = Label(self.master, text = 'example: 20160101')
        self.s_date_label2.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky = W)

        self.datetype_var = IntVar()
        R1 = Radiobutton(self.master, text="20160101", variable=self.datetype_var, value=8)
        R1.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky = W)
        R1.select()
        R2 = Radiobutton(self.master, text="201601", variable=self.datetype_var, value=6)
        R2.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky = W)
        R3 = Radiobutton(self.master, text="2016", variable=self.datetype_var, value=4)
        R3.grid(row=row, column=3, sticky = W)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Note that the parent (first argument passed to `Label` and `Entry` constructors), are changed from `self` to `self.master`.

Also the parent for `Radiobutton` are also changed from `root` to `self.master`, because then `root` is a reference to the global variable, and not the actual parent set for `Window` object.

**Update (description)**

The code on the question is adding the `Label` and `Entry` widgets to `self` (the `Window` object), so when calling `grid` on them it's using the `grid` layout *of the window object*. But the window object itself, was not added to the `root (Tk)`, so basically the `window` object and it's attached widgets would not show at all.

The `Radiobutton` instances however, were attached to `root`, so calling `grid` on them would add them to layout manager of the `root (Tk)`, that's why they were showing.

One fix for this, is to keep using `root` as the parent for all widgets, which causes the window object to be like a data container, but not a widget on the UI.

**Approach 2**

Add the window object itself to the layout manager of the `root`. Something like this:

```
#all the code is the same as the question
# ...
app = Window(root)
app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW)
# the rest of the code
```

But remember that if you'd like to use this approach (using the window object as a Widget container as well), then again I'd suggest that all the `Radiobutton` to use `self` (the window object) as their parents instead of `root`. Because when using `root` as the parent, calling `grid(row=0, column=0)` on radio buttons, they would be using the same row/column that the window object (frame) is using.

Comment: Can I ask you an extra question?

Comment: Thank you! At the first time I try to use place() to build the layout. And I write this in the beginning in init_window(self): self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1).

Comment: If do so, I don't have to change every self to self.master. I want to know why

Comment: I updated the answer with more description. But I used the `grid` layout manager in the answer again, instead of `pack` that you used. But the reasoning is the same.

Comment: @MarsLee You're welcome. I hope the updated description made it clear why it's like that, otherwise let me know.

Comment: It makes no sense to use `self.master` as the parent of the widgets. The class they are in is itself a `Frame`, so any children of this class should use `self` as the root.  Either that, or this class should _not_ inherit from Frame.

Comment: I agree @BryanOakley that it's the better way to use the frame itself as the parent (as was suggested as another approach). Thanks for your comment. I updated the answer to suggest the readers the second approach instead of the first one.

Comment: I am really appreciate for what both you have done for me! This is extremely helpful. I am still studying it thought. Give me more time haha!

Answer (score 2):

`app` is an instance of `Window`. `Window` is a `Frame`. The widgets created by `init_window` sometimes have `self` as the parent, and sometimes `root`. The first thing you need to fix is that they all need to have a  parent of `self`. The point of this sort of design, which you've no doubt copied from somewhere, is that everything inside this class should be contained in this frame.

Because `app` is an instance of `Window` and `Window` is a subclass of `Frame`, everything that goes in this widget will be invisible unless `app` is visible. So, the second part of the solution is to make `app` visible. You can do this however you want. In this particular case, since it's the only widget in the root window, I would use pack:

```
app = Window(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: I have one question. You said "Because app is an instance of Window and Window is a subclass of Frame, everything that goes in this widget will be invisible unless app is visible." So if I use pack(), it will make app visible?

Comment: @MarsLee: if you call `pack()` on `app`, yes, it will make `app` visible. This is no different from any other widget.

Answer (score 1):

You're making the label and entry their own parents and not starting their own event loops. Instead of `self`, try changing their parent to `root`.